# Is it possible to add new table attribute with serverside data in Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery

Currently what i get against my every table row is

`<tr id="123" class="odd" data-title="abc">`

I am adding data-title attributes using

`"fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {

                $(nRow).attr('data-title', 'abc'); }`

what i want to accomplish is to get my value instead of abc for data-title attribute in table row, is their any way of doing this in datatables? My data comes from serverside as
`{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":193,"iTotalDisplayRecords":193,"aaData":[{"UserId":0,"DT_RowId":123, "Data_Title": "Test"}]}`

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: you wanted to select the data from json response `Data_Title` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

Assuming `aData` is `{"UserId":0,"DT_RowId":123, "Data_Title": "Test"}`

```
"fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
$(nRow).attr('data-title', aData['Data_Title']); }
```

if a is complete json `{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":193,"iTotalDisplayRecords":193,"aaData":[{"UserId":0,"DT_RowId":123, "Data_Title": "Test"}]}` and `iDataIndex` is the index of the record in the array then:-

then :-

```
$(nRow).attr('data-title', aData['aaData'][iDataIndex]['Data_Title']); }
```

Comment: Thanks @PSL, my aData is complete json but for some reason, this worked ````$(nRow).attr('data-title', aData['Data_Title']); }```` instead of ````iDataIndex```` one

Comment: Another way it works is ````$(nRow).attr('data-title', aData.Data_Title);````

Comment: Yes that is another way to access Json properties